# Python dict.update() with C++ std::map?

Tags: python, c++, c++11

In Python, I can do this:

```
>>> foo = {1: 10, 2: 20}
>>> foo.update({1: 150, 5: 500})
>>> foo
{1: 150, 2: 20, 5: 500}
```

How to replicate the same in C++ with `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`?
Some *standard algorithm* maybe?

Off course, one can roll a straightforward loop — but that's not succinct enough.

Comment: I think you are stuck with rolling out your own helper function. Standard library map insertion methods do not replace existing elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) and [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) overloads that take an `std::initializer_list` and offer a similar functionality. But these only to up-date non-existing elements.

To replicate the `dict.update` behaviour, you could roll out your own helper function:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
void update_map(std::map<K,V>& m, 
                std::initializer_list<typename std::map<K,V>::value_type> l)
{
  for (const auto& p : l)
    m[p.first] = p.second;
}


std::map<int, int> m { {1, 10}, {2, 20} };
update_map(m, {{1, 150}, {5, 500}});

for (const auto& p : m)
{
  std::cout  << "{" << p.first << ", " << p.second << "}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
{1, 150}
{2, 20}
{5, 500}
```

Comment: There's a `template<class InputIterator> std::{map, unordered_map}::insert(InputIterator, InputIterator)` as well.

Comment: @Casey Thanks. I had to change the whole thing anyway. `std::map::insert` is not analogous to `dict.update`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `[]` operator for `std::map`
the `[]` operator will insert non-existing elements and replace existing elements.

```
std::map<int, int> foo {{1,10}, {2,20}};
foo[1] = 150;
foo[5] = 500;
```

The resulting foo contains `{1,150}, {2,20}, {5,500}`

Would this suit your needs?

Comment: Actually not, it doesn't quite work with `.update()` argument stored in a variable. One has to write a loop anyway.